# Does my spouse qualify for an interview waiver on her first US J-2 application if I do for my renewal?

Tags: interview

I am currently on an expired J-1 that's not yet 48 months after expiration and am renewing it. It's quite possible that I qualify for an interview waiver. At the same time I want to bring my wife thus she needs a J-2. It will be her first J-2 application.

Comment: Welcome to our community! I was on the J1 as well, but didn't run into this situation. Hopefully you enjoy Travel.SE !